# I can't install AWS SAM CLI using HomeBrew. It keeps throwing me this error in the terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to install the AWS SAM CLI using HomeBrew but keep getting an error after I run the following commands:

brew tap aws/tap

brew install aws-sam-cli

And then I get this error:
aws-sam-cli: Failed to download resource "gdbm"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gdbm/blobs/sha256:7abb94a713a1e25f5fc4c5218067abf6ad09bbd68967c21f01d5d69f88308dd4

I am following the instructions on AWS site here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-mac.html

I have tried troubleshooting by going to this page : https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1987

but nothing works.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and solved it by:

1. updating homebrew with `brew update`
2. running those two commands again